# Action before http call Angular/RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is any solution for call action before api call using rxjs in angular?

For example, I want:

1. Start loader
2. Get data from server
3. End loader

I want to do this in one 'pipe'

```
return this.customersService
      .getById(id)
      .pipe(
        actionBefore( () => this.startLoading() ) // <= I need this 
        switchMap(async (data) => {
          this.customer$.next(data);
          return data;
        }),
        finalize(() => this.endLoading())
      );
```

Comment: Can you not just put it outside/before the Observable pipeline?

Comment: @ChrisYungmann If I call a function, that return observable, and not subscribe to it, I get an infinity loader

Answer (score 1):

you can use Angular interceptor in order to achieve that. So whenever an HTTP request is going on, the loading will be shown. in order for that, you need to create a loading service, loading interceptor (you can also create a loading component to implement something like a progress bar)

Loading Service:

```html
import { Overlay, OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, NEVER, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, share } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoadingComponent } from '../shared/components/loading/loading.component';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoadingService {
  private overlayRef?: OverlayRef;
  isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay) {}

  public show(): void {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
    Promise.resolve(null).then(() => {
      this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
        positionStrategy: this.overlay.position().global().centerHorizontally().centerVertically(),
        hasBackdrop: true,
      });
      this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(LoadingComponent));
    });
  }

  public readonly spinner$ = defer(() => {
    this.show();
    return NEVER.pipe(finalize(() => this.hide()));
  }).pipe(share());

  public hide(): void {
    this.isLoading.next(false);
    this.overlayRef!.detach();
    this.overlayRef = undefined;
  }
}
```

your loading interceptor:

```html
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoadingService } from './services/loading.service';
@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly loadingService: LoadingService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const spinnerSubscription: Subscription = this.loadingService.spinner$.subscribe();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => spinnerSubscription.unsubscribe()));
  }
}
```

you need to provide this interceptor in your app.module.ts like this:

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoadingInterceptor } from './laodingInterceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoadingInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following would do the trick, but I think it would be easier to read if you just put `startLoading` outside the whole observable pipeline

```js
return of(null)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.startLoading()),
    switchMap(() => this.customersService.getById(id)),
    tap(data => this.customers$.next(data)),
    finalize(() => this.endLoading())
  );
```

Alternatively, using `defer`:

```js
return defer(() => {
  this.startLoading();
  return this.customerService.getById(id)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => this.customers$.next(data)),
      finalize(() => this.endLoading())
    );
});
```

Alternative, using `new Observable`:

```js
return new Observable(subscriber => {
  this.startLoading();
  this.customerService.getById(id)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => this.customers$.next(data)),
      finalize(() => this.endLoading())
    ).subscribe(subscriber);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do start the loading before the observable call and end the loading in the last operator in the pipe:

```js
this.startLoading();

return this.customersService
      .getById(id)
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          this.customer$.next(data);
          this.endLoading();
          return data;
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          this.endLoading(); // also finish loading if there was an error
          throwError(err);
        })
      );
```